# Can iPad show percentage when charging by USB, and does iPad 2 charge slowly too?

Tags: charging, ipad

I found that my iPad might be half charged after a few hours by USB from PC... too bad I can't find the wall adapter...  but when I turn it on, it says "Not charging" without saying the Percentage it already has charged up.  Can it show somehow?  Maybe by tapping the "Not charging" message but I don't really need to see it so many times. (but tapping doesn't work)

Does the iPad 2 also have the same issue of slow charging too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get the Not Charging message is because most machines don't send enough power through USB to charge the iPad. The iPads battery is more like a laptop battery than a phone battery. Newer Macs will send enough power over some of their USB ports.

As for the percentage, If you turn on "Battery Percentage" I think under Settings, General, Usage. This should show it up in the top right.

Due to the iPad 1 and 2 sharing many other similarities, the iPad 2 should also display the 'not charging' message. Although, a new iPad 2 will come with a Wall Charger as well. You can purchase off-brand chargers on amazon or ebay, extra wall chargers at the apple store, and some [third party companies make chargers like Griffin](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/powerblock-for-ipad)

Comment: I already have the battery percentage turned on.  But when it is charging it won't show.  I don't want to unplug just to see the percentage and plug it in again.  A lot of your answers are "I think"... when the question is answered, nobody else really bother to answer again, at least in the near future.

Comment: I updated my answer to remove the 'i Thinks', I wrote those because I am not beside my iPad right now. Even without the actual percentage, it should show up a visual representation of how much it has charged. But your main issue is that your computer does not send enough power over USB to charge the iPad.